# SimpleDateFormat fails to reject input missing century on the year of the input, despite "yyyy" in the formatting pattern

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have a SimpleDateFormat with the pattern `yyyy-M-d"`, and the following scenario:

```
String str = "02-03-04";        
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d");
f.setLenient(false);
System.out.println(f.parse(str));
```

The output is `Sat Mar 04 00:00:00 EST 2`

My goal was to only catch dates in the format like 2004-02-03 and to ignore 02-03-04. I thought the yyyy in the pattern would require a 4 digit year, but clearly this is not the case. Can anyone explain why this is not throwing a parse exception? I would like it to...

Comment: Aside from using more specific API, a regex should also work (just check that it matches, and then use the parser).

Comment: I simplified the problem for this post. In reality,I have a bunch of date formats that match various patterns. In hindsight, maybe regexes (or JODA time) would have been better...but this is where I'm at now.

Comment: if it's tacking on stuff, then i really can't propose a better method than validating first using regexes (it should be easy enough to write one regex per date pattern, considering that the date pattern would catch the other errors in the format?).

Comment: ah! or you could use `set2DigitYearStart` to place it at an "impossible" value, like something ridiculously far in the future (though it sounds too much like y2k), and check it (like Jon's answer suggests)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I can explain it from [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year):

> For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.

It's possible that [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) would be stricter - and it's a better API in general, IMO...

You could always throw an exception if the year is less than 1000 after parsing...

Comment: +1, This bit me recently and was a bit unnerving when I was debugging and saw that my dates were from the year `10` :|

Comment: Throwing if the year is less than 1000 won't work. What if the user actually intends it and enters `0002-03-04`?

Comment: I agree that using Joda Time would be better. But this is a larger part of an application which I cannot switch at the current time. I will certainly look into switching in the future though.

Comment: If I wanted to catch both 2004-02-03 and 02-03-04 with two different date formats, is there no easy way to do this?

Comment: @Jeff: What do you mean by "catch"?

Comment: @lijie: Good catch... although it may well be that that isn't an issue for this app :)

Comment: @Jon: I agree. Just pointing out potential assumptions. I think that "catch" means "differentiate" (in the english sense, as in, differentiate 2004-02-03 and 02-03-04)

Comment: That was a poor choice to use the word "catch" in a Java question. Yes, I did mean differentiate. So basically if I had a list of valid formats, what two formats could I use to differentiate between those to dates. I'm thinking I may need to go to a regex (or Joda) solution...

Comment: @Jeff: Well, you could try to parse it with both - it will only be valid and with a reasonable year with one format.

Comment: This behavior on the part of SimpleDateFormat is RIDICULOUS! What is the point of having patterns if their parser does not adhere to them?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Using *java.time*, that input with that formatting pattern fails, just as you expected.

```
LocalDate
.parse(
    "02-03-04" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuu-M-d" )
)
```

…throws `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`

## java.time

The classes you were using are now supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 and built into Java 8 and later.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

Define a custom formatting pattern as you asked. Use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuu-M-d" );
```

Try to parse your input.

```
String input = "02-03-04";
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse ( input , f );
```

We encounter a [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html), failing on the missing century of the year of the input. Just as you expected.

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '02-03-04' could not be parsed at index 0

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).